# Configure error in Mac OS X Lion 10.7 -- Library 'crypto' is required for OpenSSL

Tags: macos, postgresql, openssl, homebrew

Tried `brew install postgres` and got the following error:

```
datadir=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.2.4/share/postgresql --docdir=/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql
checking for library containing gss_init_sec_context... -lgssapi_krb5
checking for library containing com_err... none required
checking for library containing krb5_sendauth... none required
checking for CRYPTO_new_ex_data in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: library 'crypto' is required for OpenSSL
```

OpenSSL seems to be installed correctly (I brew installed it, with no complaints, and brew doctor doesn't raise any flags about it), and my XCode developer tools are also up to date. Looked around for how to install crypto on a mac, (OS X Lion 10.7), and there are surprisingly few resources. Any ideas what's wrong or how to fix it?

I tried uninstalling/reinstalling OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ended up being based on an inexplicably empty libcrypto.dylib file. There was a backup (libcrypto.dylib.BAK), and I just overwrote the empty file with it and all the problems went away. No idea how that happened in the first place, but if anyone's having similar problems, I'd look for .BAK files in usr/lib/ and (if there are any) see if the associated files are empty.

Answer (score -2):

For cryptography, PostgreSQL use **Zlib**, so, you need to install Zlib headers in your Mac, to be able to compile it with crypto support. You can see an [example](http://blog.endpoint.com/2013/06/installing-postgresql-without-root.html) but is for Ubuntu. You need to figure out how to install zlib in [Mac](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/zlib.3.html):

To read more about the pgcrypto module, [visit this link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/pgcrypto.html).

Comment: "brew install zlib" seemed to install it just fine, but then running "brew install postgres" again ran into the same issues. I tried to look at the brew installation file, but it didn't seem to include any way to include that crypto library.

Comment: Zlib is a compression library. PostregSQL uses it for compression.